# Error: Package 'NETStandard.Library.Ref 2.1.0' has a package type 'DotnetPlatform' that is not supported by project '...'

Tags: nuget, .net-standard, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.1

When I try to install NETStandard.Library.Ref from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library.Ref), I get in Packet Manager console this error:
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Looking at the package on nuget.org (your link), the readme says "do not reference directly".  What are you trying to achieve by installing it (referencing it) directly?

Comment: When I publish my application, I get the error:

`System.IO.FileLoadException
Message : Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies.`
And I read on a forum that this action could help me solve the error.

Comment: Try using the latest versions of VS 2019 or VS 2022, then a correct version of netstandard.dll should be referenced automatically when needed during the build. Are you perhaps using VS 2017? (that would not be supported)

Comment: @MartinUllrich I have updated as suggested, but I have the same error. Do you have, please, any other ideas?

Comment: If it is a web project (classic ASP.NET), you might need some web.config binding redirect changes - there should be a warning in the VS list for that which can be right clicked and fixed

Comment: netstandard 2.1 is special, the legacy framework (4.x) and UWP have no support for it.  Only usable in .NETCore (.NET5+), Mono, Xamarin and Unity.  Which is what the crummy error message is trying to tell you.  The additions in 2.1 can only work on a newer version of the CLR (aka CoreCLR).  Typical workaround is to find the Nuget package that requires it and finding an older version of it that still targets netstandard 2.0